# Why do plants look different at the end of Justice League (2017) movie?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

At the end of the *Justice League (2017)* movie, the growing plants look very unusual.

[image]

I know Cyborg and Superman have stopped the Mother Boxes forming Unity but still the plants look different.  Why so?

Comment: When the JL are arguing how to bring back Superman, Batman says, ***The Mother Box was designed to reshape a planet***. So when the Mother-boxes combined together briefly, they could have done some *reshaping* of the flora within a specific range. I will give a detailed answer in sometime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will base my answer only on the ***Justice League-2017*** movie plot and what the DCEU explains about the Mother-boxes. According to the [DCEU](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Mother_Box),

> A **Mother Box**, also called a Change Engine, is a perpetual energy matrix of Apokoliptian origin.

It's powers (although not much explored in the JL-2017 movie), include:

1. Biological manipulation
2. Boom-tube generation
3. Terraformation

According to [here](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Mother_Box),

> **Biological Manipulation**: Mother Boxes are able to *manipulate life on a cellular level*, including augmentations of biological functions, by utilizing a unique energy field.

In the movie, the Mother boxes were briefly reunited by Steppenwolf before being separated by Superman and Cyborg. So during that brief moment, there could have  been some unknown effects created by the Mother boxes leading to the plant life changing appearance (as they could have been modified at a molecular level).

Another evidence is what Batman says when the team is discussing on the way to bring back Superman. Batman says to the Flash :

> The Mother Box was designed to ***reshape*** a planet.

In conclusion, it is highly possible that the merging of the three Mother-boxes could have led to some changes in the life-forms around them within a specific range.

Comment: All your sources come from the wiki, which unless sourced to elsewhere (in which case you should get the information from there) is fan-written.